# connecting to a database in OrientDB console

Tags: orientdb

I'm trying to connect to the GratefulDeadConcerts without any sucess.
I'm using docker.

```
orientdb> connect remote:localhost root root

Disconnecting from the database [null]...OK
Connecting to remote Server instance [remote:localhost] with user 'root'...OK
orientdb {server=remote:localhost/}> list databases

Found 5 databases:

* VehicleHistoryGraph (plocal)
* GratefulDeadConcerts (plocal)
* OpenBeer (plocal)
* BetterDemo (plocal)
* Tolkien-Arda (plocal)



orientdb {server=remote:localhost/}> connect plocal:../databases/GratefulDeadConcerts root root

Disconnecting from remote server [remote:localhost/]...
OK
Connecting to database [plocal:../databases/GratefulDeadConcerts] with user 'root'...
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open local storage '../databases/GratefulDeadConcerts' with mode=rw
        DB name="GratefulDeadConcerts"

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open the storage 'GratefulDeadConcerts' because it does not exist in path: ../databases/GratefulDeadConcerts
        DB name="GratefulDeadConcerts"
```

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Reading again the question, you're connected to a server in remote mode and then you're trying to connect to a database in plocal, that means embedded mode. You should connect to any of the db using remote connection: connect remote:localhost/<DBNAME> admin admin

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

> connect remote:localhost/GratefulDeadConcerts root root

Answer (score 0):

The official Docker image comes without a database inside: the gratefulDeadConcerts isn't included. This is because usually a volume where to store databases is provided, and a demo database increases the size of the image. 
You don't show the command you are using to launch the container, but I suppose you have read the doc (https://hub.docker.com/_/orientdb/) and you're using something like that:

```
docker run -d --name orientdb -p 2424:2424 -p 2480:2480 \
-v <config_path>:/orientdb/config \
-v <databases_path>:/orientdb/databases \
-v <backup_path>:/orientdb/backup \
-e ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpwd \
orientdb
```

Point your browser to localhost:2480 and download a db from our site: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Studio-Home-page.html

Wrapping up:
- read the doc about the image un docker hub
- read the doc about studio and how to import a public database

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this?

```
connect remote:localhost/databases/GratefulDeadConcerts root root
```

Answer (score 0):

Decide you want to connect remote or to the local server itself,

1.if it is local use plocal

orientdb> CONNECT plocal:../databases/databasename username password

2. if it is remote sever

orientdb> CONNECT remote:192.168.1.1/databasename username password